# Change background on one List Item in a listbox (Not the selected item)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` for `addresses`.  Each item is a formatted address label using `DataTemplate`.

When the user selects an item in the list AND clicks `Set to default` button, I would like to change the background color of that item to denote the default.

I only want to change that one item, NOT the `SelectedItem`... so the `SelectedItem` might be one color and the DEFAULT might be a different color.

I would like to do this pragmatically... even if I need a loop to reset the non-default and set the default...

My problem is that the `ListBox.SelectedItem` only allows me access to the underlying object in the collection, in this case `Address`.

So, the following will not work:

```
foreach (ListBoxItem item in lstShipToAddresses.Items)
{
   // does not work (can't cast Address to ListboxItem) 
   item.Background = Brushes.Magenta;        
}
```

How can I access the background of a particular `ListBoxItem`?

I have a plan `B` which involves just using another area outside the `ListBox` to display the default `address`, but that would gobble up a bit more screen space, so I'm trying to avoid that.

**Update (XAML)**:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         Name="lstShipToAddresses"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ocShipToAddress}"
         SelectionChanged="lstShipToAddresses_SelectionChanged"
         SelectedValuePath="Address_ID">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Address_Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Final Solution:**

This code is done within the button click, so the `SelectedItem` is the one we want to make default.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstShipToAddresses.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (lstShipToAddresses.Items[i] == lstShipToAddresses.SelectedItem)
    {
        // Set background on default
        var listBoxItem = lstShipToAddresses.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        (listBoxItem as ListBoxItem).Background = Brushes.Magenta;
    }
    else
    {
        // Reset background on non-default 
        var listBoxItem = lstShipToAddresses.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        (listBoxItem as ListBoxItem).Background = Brushes.White;
    }
}
```

- Might need to change the Magenta to a less scary color ;)

Comment: You can use ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: what if you did the following instead to see if it changes the color @pStan
`item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);` then if it does use your `Magenta` color

Comment: The item is of type "Address", so it does not have the property "Background"

Comment: @pStan...Can you show your XAML?

Comment: You need a property, something like Background or IsDefault...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromindex(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose. It returns a `DependencyObject` then you can cast it to `ListBoxItem` and use the `ListBoxItem`'s properties like `Background`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstShipToAddresses.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var listBoxItem = lstShipToAddresses.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
    (listBoxItem as ListBoxItem).Background = Brushes.Magenta; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  That is what I need.

Comment: @pStan...You're Welcome. :)  Also I think if you update your question and change it's title to `Unable to cast object of type 'Address' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.` you will help the future visitor to find your question more.